# Updating date format within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change the date format within a df using pandas. My current code looks like this:

```html
data = pd.read_csv('pub?gid=31644116&single=true&output=csv', 
                 usecols=[0,1,2], 
                 header=0,
                 encoding="utf-8-sig",
                 index_col='Day Index')


data['Revenue'] = data['Revenue'].str.replace(',','').str.replace('£','').astype('float')
data['E-commerce Conversion Rate'] = data['E-commerce Conversion Rate'].str.replace('%','').astype('float')

data.apply(pd.to_numeric)

print("we have a total of:", len(data), " samples")

data.head()
```

And returns this:

```html
we have a total of: 109  samples
Revenue E-commerce Conversion Rate
Day Index       
01/05/2020  4396.89 0.99
02/05/2020  7117.02 1.60
03/05/2020  3248.22 1.04
04/05/2020  8843.80 1.93
05/05/2020  5863.42 1.54
```

I am wanting to update the date format from D/M/Y to Y-M-D. When I add the below line, I am getting the following error:

```html
data['Day Index']=pd.to_datetime(data['Day Index'].astype(str), format='%y-%m-%d')

KeyError: 'Day Index'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Is the issue because I am setting the "Day Index" column as the index_col? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If need convert index values use `data.index` and change format of datetimes for match `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
data.index=pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Also in your code is not assign output of converted values to numeric, use:

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the yearfirst parameter instead of format. Hope this helps:

```
    yearfirst=True
```